# Where is the build.properties file located for an Eclipse Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to import my Eclipse Java Project into Visual Studio Code using WPILib, and it asks to select the location of my `build.properties` file located in the root directory of my project, however, I cannot locate it. I even attempted a search and could not locate it. Is there a way to create it? There seems to be no straight answer on the internet for this, either.

Comment: There isn't one. Eclipse does not use a `build.properties`. That is a VS Code specific thing.

Comment: How would I import it into VSCode then? If I just drag the folder over there are tons of errors.

Comment: Probably best to start a new Java project and then copy the Java files one by one. Good luck!

Comment: Can you just open the project? In VS Code the Java language support _is_ Eclipse.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why would this be necessary? VS Code Java language support _is_ Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I don't use VS Code for Java development. I didn't say it was necessary. I was thinking "easy". Feel free to actually answer. This is just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Turn to **`.Project`** and delete `<nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature> </natures>`. This sentence will quote `build.properties`, which is not existed.

Try this and see if the question goes away.